# Fazer as divs ficarem inline

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, estou tndo problema para deixar esse box abaixo com o display inline, a div box é a div que engloba tudo, a div hentaiBox é a div de cada box, atulamente ficam todos em cascata não sei por que, e eu gostaria que eles ficassem um do lado do outro, e qunado não couber mais na tela fique em baixo.
O código css está no final.

```css
.hentaiBox>a>img {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.hentaiBox>a>img:hover {
  width: 175px;
  height: 225px;
}

.nota {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nomeAnime {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.episodiosAnime {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.comentario {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify
}

.genero {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.p2 {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
    <p class="nota">Nota:
      <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
    <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
    <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olha a minha dica é colocar `flex` no `container pai`, mas tb colocar `flex` no `container filho`, assim, vc pode ter a imagem em uma coluna e o texto ao lado em outra coluna. Para separa o texto e imagem e deixar tudo semântico no `container pai` usei a tag `<figure>` e o texto eu coloquei dentro ta tag `<figcaption>`. Assim ficou mais organizado, mas semântico e manteve o alinhamento com o texto ao lado da imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segue o código da imagem acima**

```css
.hentaiBox>a>img {
  /* float: left; */
  width: 170px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.hentaiBox>a>img:hover {
  width: 175px;
  height: 225px;
}

.nota {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nomeAnime {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.episodiosAnime {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.comentario {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify
}

.genero {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.p2 {
  color: gray;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.hentaiBox {
  display: flex;
  height: 225px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 16px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <figure class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
      <p class="nota">Nota:
        <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
      <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
      <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
      <p class="nota">Nota:
        <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
      <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
      <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <figcaption>
      <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
      <p class="nota">Nota:
        <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
      <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
      <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>

</div>
```

Comment: vlw man, ajudou bastante, porém quando eu passo o hover é ativado ele empurra tudo um pouco para o lado, gostaria que apenas a imagem ficasse maior.

Comment: @predo_json vc reparou que no seu CSS quando vc coloca o `img:hover` vc amenta o `width` de 170px para 175px, ai acaba deslocando mesmo o que está em volta. Se vc quiser uma outra opção mude seu código e coloque um `width` apenas 170px, e no `img:hover` vc pode colocar `transform: scale(1.1)` Outra coisa, vc só pode marcar uma resposta como aceita, quando vc marca outra resposta ela fica valendo como a resposta aceita. Então considere qual resposta realmente atendeu seu problema e marque ela, vc não pode marcar duas resposta com ✔ ok

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta esta um pouco confusa.. Pelo o que eu entendi acredito que utilizando display flex com um flex-wrap (pra ficar embaixo quando não couber mais) resolva seu problema..

```css
.hentaiBox>a>img {
  float: left;
  width: 170px;
  height: 220px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.hentaiBox>a>img:hover {
  width: 175px;
  height: 225px;
}

.nota {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.nomeAnime {
  font-size: 19px;
}

.episodiosAnime {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.comentario {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: justify
}

.genero {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: gray;
}

.p2 {
  color: gray;
}

/* Display flex */ 
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 40rem;
}
   .hentaiBox {
 margin: .2rem;
   }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
    <p class="nota">Nota:
      <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
    <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
    <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
    <p class="nota">Nota:
      <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
    <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
    <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
    <p class="nota">Nota:
      <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
    <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
    <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="hentaiBox">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="~/images.jpg" />
    </a>
    <p class="nomeAnime">Nome do anime</p>
    <p class="nota">Nota:
      <font color="light-green">98</font> pontos</p>
    <p class="episodiosAnime">4 episódio - completo</p>
    <p class="genero">Genero1, Genero2</p>
  </div>
</div>
```